# How to fill up my dropdown from my service?

Tags: ng-dropdown-multiselect

iam trying to fill up an ng-multiselect-dropdown From my clientservice ,  i can fetch my clients from database , but i don't know the correct syntax to send id and name to populate my list !

i have tried alot of examples with out any success ,was almost there,

What i tried so far :

```
    this.dropdownList = 
         this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(
      data => this.clients = data,
      error => console.log(error),
     () => this.isLoading = false

     )};
```

here is my service file

```
     getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
     return this.HttpClient.get<Client[]>('/api/clients');}
```

model :

```
     export class Client {
     _id?: string;
     name?: string;
     address?: string;
     zipcode?: number;
     city?: string;
     email?: string;
     phone?: string;
     }
```

HTML :

```
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
    [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
    [data]="clients"
    [selectedItems]=selectedItems;
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
     >
     </ng-multiselect-dropdown >


     [Populated with [data]= clients[https://imgur.com/a/D1WFMlw]
```

am expecting a function to ( this.dropdownList = ) and populate my list from my service .so far i got aclients Objects list populated, i need to populate the client name and id :)

thank you all guys .

Comment: Try [data] ="clients"

Comment: CE James , thanks for your answer , i tried with [data]= "clients" i got an objects list , i need to fetch only client name and id !